# Changing manuscript title

Tags: publications, peer-review

My manuscript Biology/Ecology) was accepted in a journal with minor revisions to do. The reviewers have no comment and suggestion to the title, but would it be ok if I change it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases here. From the question it is unclear.

1. The article has directly been sent to production team after the peer review
2. The authors have been asked to correct the minor revisions after the peer review

In the case 1, it is somewhat difficult. Because production manager would be in contact with you. A title change has to be approved by Chief-Editor of the journal prior to production in this case. So, you may wish to contact the chief editor asking is it okay, with giving a suitable reason for the change.

In case 2, you can edit the online title in the journal submission system (e.g. EES, Evise, ScholarOne, EditorialManager .. ). But, again it is wise to mention this in a cover letter to the Chief Editor accompanied with the revised submission.